# Event or Mutex?

Tags: events, mutex, critical-section

I currently have a program running with about 20 threads at a time. I am fairly new to multi-threading so I'm a little confused on proper data protection.

Currently, my threads use Events as data locks an unlocks. I opted to use this over critical sections as most data is only shared between two or three threads so preventing a single thread from reading while one wrote by stopping all 20 threads seemed wasteful. I used Event over Mutex simply due to the fact that I could not (easily) find a source that clearly explained how a Mutex works and how to implement one.

I'm using Win32 API for my multi-threading. In my current setup I use Events to lock data so my event would be something like "DataUnlock" When not set I know that the data is being worked on. When set I know it is ok to work on the data. So my makeshift data locks look something like this.

```
WaitForSingleObject( DataUnlock,INFINITE );    //Wait until the Data is free  
ResetEvent(DataUnlock);                     //Signal that the data is being worked on   
...work on Data...    
SetEvent(DataUnlock);                       //Signal that the data is free to use
```

My first question is: Is this as good (efficient) as using a Mutex when only two threads are accessing the data?

Second: If more than two threads waiting to access the data is there a potential that both will be triggered when the data is freed (will the both pass the wait before one reaches ResetEvent)? If so, would a mutex have the same issue?

Lastly: If a mutex is preferable, how would I go about implementing one (a link or explanation would be greatly appreciated)?

Thanks!

Comment: I stared very closely at your code snippet above. That snippet will allow other threads to `...work on Data...`. Hence, your snippet does not guarantee `mutual exclusion` on `...work on Data...`. Nanoseconds after `WaitForSingleObject` has unblocked, **but** before `ResetEvent`, another thread also unblocks. Both threads are happy to continue with a free flowing call sequence of `ResetEvent`, `...work on Data...` and `SetEvent` as these API's are non-blocking. If that is your intended behavior, then your snippet is fine. It's all in the intent.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the event approach is the best way of protecting the data.

Look at [Mutex Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Using Mutex Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to learn about mutexes.

1. One of your threads has to create a mutex. The  [CreateMutex function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  returns a handle to the mutex object. You can pass the handle as an argument to the threads dealing with your data.
2. Use the [WaitForSingleObject function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to wait for the mutex and then process your data. Release the mutex with a call to the [ReleaseMutex function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). When a mutex is released the next wait function will gain the mutex.
3. In case the data is to be accessed by threads of multiple processes, named mutexes have to be used.

Look at [Critical Section Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  to learn about critical section synchronisation.

If you want to have the

1. A critical section has to be created by a call to the [InitializeCriticalSection function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
2. Use the [EnterCriticalSection function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at all places before you handle your data.
3. The [LeaveCriticalSection function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) releases the critical section releases the object. Use this call after you're done with the data.

The critical section can only be entered by the owning thread. Once a thread has gained the critical section object, no other thread can get access to your data. Other threads will block at the call to `EnterCriticalSection()`. However the thread owns the critical section can do succesive calls to `EnterCriticalSection()` more than once. Care shall be taken to call `LeaveCriticalSection()` once for **every** call to `EnterCriticalSection()`.

Your example would let all threads waiting for the event process your data. And you would only know by the data themself if processing of anykind has happened. That's up to you, 
how to determine what was done and what still needs to be done. If you have many threads waiting for your event, you can't tell the order in which the get access.

---

I would recommend using a critical section object. It is lightweight and relatively easy to use. See [Using Critical Section Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for an example how to use critical section objects.